# The data must be identical, and the test should be successful. Data are identical, but the test failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I am testing method `last_photo`:

```
def last_photo
  @last_photo ||= user_updates.latest.where("photo_front IS NOT NULL and photo_front != ''").first.try(:photo_front)
end
```

Spec:

```
context "instance method" do
  let(:user) { create :user }

  context "last photo" do
    before { create_list(:user_update, 3, user: user) }
    let(:user_updates){ user.user_updates }

    describe "#last_photo" do
      subject { user.last_photo }

      it { should eq user_updates.latest.first.photo_front }
    end
  end
end
```

the test should be successful. But there are strange error.

Attached [GIST](https://gist.github.com/vadus1/9761816).

Comment: Could you show us how you define `photo_front`?

Comment: @BroiSatse `photo_front` this is a photo uploaded by user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple really:

```
expected: #<PhotoUploader:0x00000007e34868 ...
got: #<PhotoUploader:0x00000007ebc100 ...
```

The values might be the same, but the objects are different in memory. Since you're doing a comparison on the objects, rspec expects the objects to be the exact same.

Now, `user.user_updates` and `user_updates` are two different variables in memory. You should do a comparison on the values.